# SQLite no such table in C#

Tags: sqlite

**I write this C# Code for insert one text data to my database table:**

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=tDB1.sqlite;Version=3;");
string q1 = "INSERT INTO tMembers(mName) VALUES(?)";

SQLiteCommand cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand(q1, con);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mName", txtName.Text);

con.Open(); 
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close();
```

I copy my tDB1.sqlite  to my program folder and Create tMembers table in sqlite.

when i run my program,  program debugger show ""cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();""  line and display to me:  SQLite error no such table

can any help me?
thank you.

Comment: Might it be a syntax error? Do you need a space between `tMembers` and `(mName)` in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: try to ensure the db is in the same folder of th executable, not just in the program folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little to weak look for a file based just on current directory. If you are sure the database is placed exactly in the same dir of the executable ( that is when debugging from visual studio $`projectdir$\bin\debug` you can enforce the path as in the following code:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"tdb1.sqlite"))
    );
```

Comment: "It is a little to weak look for a file based just on current directory."   what is the best way to addressing a database? thank you

Comment: @ramin the one I shown is a good alternative, I use all the path in whichthe exe lie + the db file name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the command string

```
string q1 = "INSERT INTO tMembers(mName) VALUES(?)";
```

to

```
string q1 = "INSERT INTO tMembers(@mName) VALUES(?)";
```

There is no need to keep corresponding to the column's name, but it must be the same with the args' name when executing the whole command. More info about this, you could search "[PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL)" in google.

Besides, did you execute this command with "VALUES(?)"? I'm not sure that could work or not, you could execute `INSERT INTO tMembers(@mName) DEFAULT VALUES` instead, if there is no NOT NULL constraint.